# Why are my bracket pairs not obeying my changes to the editorBracketHighlight.foreground# settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Need to Change the bracket color VS code. The brackets are of different colors depending on the degree of nesting

[image]

[image]

Better show it in a video

https://streamable.com/j63xct

I tried to change the color of brackets via "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1". But something overrides my settings. It's settings.json

In my settings, all the brackets are red, when I open a file in VS code, the brackets are red for 1 second, and then they become the default as in the theme again.

Editor › Bracket Pair Colorization: is Enabled

```
{
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.unicodeHighlight.allowedLocales": {
        "ru": true
    },
    "php.validate.executablePath": "",
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "RainbowBrackets.depreciation-notice": false,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "workbench.editor.untitled.hint": "hidden",
    "editor.unicodeHighlight.nonBasicASCII": false,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "update.showReleaseNotes": false,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light Modern",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#f60505fa",
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#f81f1ffa",
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground3": "#ca0d0dfa",
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground4": "#f33737fa",
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground5": "#b70707fa",
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground6": "#fe3030fa",
        "editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket.foreground": "#db6165"
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you are editing your settings.json to make them all red, but something else is editing it to something different?

Comment: Yes, some entries or extensions override my changes. I can't figure out what

Comment: Version: 1.81.1 (user setup)
Commit: 6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794
Date: 2023-08-09T22:22:42.175Z
Electron: 22.3.18
ElectronBuildId: 22689846
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

Comment: Thank you, thanks to you I found what was the matter.
It was due to the expansion of the Rainbow tags I deleted it and the colors of the brackets became like in the JSON file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through doing an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect), this issue was found to be caused by an extension- apparently [`voldemortensen.rainbow-tags`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=voldemortensen.rainbow-tags).